# cordova-plugin-purchase how to call getPurchases?

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, ionic-framework

I have implemented https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase plugin for iOS and Android. Now I need to know previous purchases of user? Do I need to register events and wrap it in setTimeout or something like?

```
  store.when("product").updated(function(p) {
    if(p.loaded && p.valid && p.state === store.APPROVED){
      console.log("APPROVED", p)
      p.finish();
    }

    if(p.loaded && p.valid && p.state === store.OWNED){
      console.log('OWNED',p)
      var receipt =  JSON.parse(p.transaction.receipt)
      receipts.push(receipt)  
    }


    // never get here but it should be
    // if(p.loaded && p.valid && p.state === store.FINISHED){
    //   console.log('FINISHED',p)   
    // }

  });

  $timeout(function () {
    deferred.resolve(receipts)
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: Are your purchases consumable or non?

Comment: @MegaAppBear They are NON-C but lets say they can be both. I am more asking about the approach and i am skeptic about timeout - see edited. Is this the only way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, From the plugin docs

> - When finished, a consumable product will get back to the VALID state, while other will enter the OWNED state.
> - Any error in the purchase process will bring a product back to the VALID state.
> - During application startup, products may go instantly from REGISTERED to APPROVED or OWNED, for example if they are purchased
>     non-consumables or non-expired subscriptions.

And that's what's currently working for me.

```
//register callbacks 
store.when("hint_points_200").approved(function(product) {            
    //user gets the product and we finish. State goes back to "valid"
    product.finish();
});
store.when("hint_points_500").approved(function(product) {                
    //user gets the product and we finish. State goes to "owned". In my app, this gets called every time
    //the application restarts, the product seems to go back to the "approved" status
    product.finish();
});    


//Register "ready" callback to check the status of the products
store.ready(function(){
    p1 = store.get("200_coins");            
    p2 = store.get("500_coins");            
    console.log("p1.state:"+p1.state);
    console.log("p1.owned:"+p1.owned); //consumable. This should be "valid".
    console.log("p2.state:"+p2.state);
    console.log("p2.owned:"+p2.owned); //non-consumable. This should be "owned". (Doesn't work for me and "approved" callback gets called)

    //you should also have "p1.transactions" and "p2.transactions"
});

store.register({
    id:    "200_coins",     
    type:  store.CONSUMABLE
}); 
store.register({
    id:    "500_coins",
    type:  store.NON_CONSUMABLE
});

//refresh
store.refresh();
```

As I explained, I found that a n**on-consumable will trigger the "approved" callback on application restart**. I had to handle it as a special case my app. You would need to do some testing to see what works for you.

Comment: thank you a lot for verbose answer. I will try it soon. Does it work for you on both iOS and Android ?

Comment: Android. I am still working on my IOS version. Haven't started on purchases use case yet. In an ideal world I shouldn't need to tweak for different platforms of course.

Comment: I don't know why, i am having NON-C products in approved state with valid receipt and my credit was charged. I would expect owned state. As you saying // This should be owned. Anyway to answer my question i will rely on - product.transactions object and not state to get previous Purchases.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to ping me any time in the private chat.

Comment: how do you test purchases. Do you also publish everytime to aplha/beta channel and wait ?

Comment: Yes. Your app has to be published (alpha is enough), you have to be a test user, and the app version you're testing with has to match the one in alpha or production. Takes a bit of time after you publish.

Comment: Yes, that testing sucks. Have encountered that after calling store.order(productId); and success purchase -  store.when(value).approved(function(p) {}) is somehow called multiple times?

Comment: Where do you register your ".when(value).approved"? can you share the code?

Comment: ah, yes my bad :-) i am registering listeners everytime i am entering view, crap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92287/discussion-between-jakub-kuchar-and-megaappbear).

Comment: have you proceed with iOS ? How are you doing ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542132/cordova-plugin-purchase-missing-receipt-on-ios-device

Comment: I am not doing IOS for now, focusing on android.